# Swap red and blue channels in application

Tags: color

I have an old application which renders with the red and blue channels swapped. Is there a way I can use a color filter or display profiles or something else to fix this? I'm willing to use a solution that's either specific to the application or global to the system so long as it can be easily toggled.

Comment: What application? I doubt this is fixable at OS-level; changing any aspect of the display profile would not be capable of literally swapping two input/output channels, afaik. It could possibly be done through a video 'effect', LUT etc, but idk how you would inject that to the app's output.

Answer (score 1):

Depending on how often you need the application you could use OBS to capture the window and aplly a filter like the [streamfx color filter](https://github.com/xaymar/obs-streamfx/wiki/Filter-Color-Grade) to the image to fix it and then view the output in the preview window. This is pretty unpractical if you want to use the application a lot, but for using it seldomly this should work.